# Maven is not automatically building default folder path in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-indigo

I am using Eclipse Indigo. I installed the maven package on eclipse. I configured the Pom and nearly everything is fine. Just maven is not building the default folder bath

> src/main/java

[image]

Here is the pom.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>TestProject</groupId>
  <artifactId>TestProject</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
   <dependencies>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.6</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
    <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.7</version>
        </dependency>
   </dependencies>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
              <source>1.6</source>
              <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
              <ajdtVersion>1.6</ajdtVersion>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </project>
```

I cleaned the project,installed and build it.... also I upgradet the project... the dependencies are all fine... no error at all.. why isn't the folder build ?

Comment: Eclipse's integration with maven is (to say at least) appalling. If you want to create a new project: create the pom and the folders, and then run `mvn eclipse:eclipse` to create the project files for eclipse. The simple solution that I've followed for a couple of years is to use the [community edition of Intellij](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/).

Comment: it worked... just one question... do I have to leave eclipse while building or is it enough to just refresh the Package Explorer...

Comment: Try right click on project, Maven > Update Project Configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse's integration with maven is (to say at least) appalling. If you want to create a new project: create the pom and the folders, and then run mvn eclipse:eclipse to create the project files for eclipse. The simple solution that I've followed for a couple of years is to use the [community edition of Intellij](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/).

---

Aswering your second question: well... again, the integration is so poor that sometimes you'll need to close and reopen the project for eclipse to read the new changes. Most of the time, a refresh + clean project will force eclipse to read the project configuration.